# Calculating intersection of a line segment with a circle on Earth's surface from latitude and longitude coordinates

Tags: intersection, excel, algorithm, spherical-geometry, power-bi

I'm working on a problem where I need to determine if a line segment between two geographical points on the Earth's surface, intersects with a circle on the Earth's surface, defined by a central point and a radius.
While I'm familiar with solving this problem on a flat Cartesian plane using X/Y coordinates, I'm struggling to apply similar concepts to geographical latitude/longitude coordinates.

Here's an example:

A line goes from Point A, to Point B. Does it intersect with a circle with center Point C & a radius of R?

Point A (Starting Point):   41°13'31.6665"S, 174°59'56.2505"E   /   41.225462917°S, 174.99895847°E

Point B (Ending Point):     41°21'37.0392"S, 175°02'05.0939"E   /   41.360288667°S, 175.03474831°E

Point C (Circle Center):    41°19'55.5003"S, 174°57'31.2172"E   /   41.332083417°S, 174.95867144°E

Radius R: 9260 meters

These are WGS84 coordinates. I've been using Excel to try get my head around it (I know it's not the quickest way, but it's been useful to try get my head around it. I would, in a dream world try do it within Power BI)

Could someone point me in the right direction for how to determine if the line from Point A to Point B intersects a circle centered at Point C with a radius of R on the Earth's spherical surface?

How can I solve this type of problem?

Comment: Solving equations on Earth's spheroid requires a code library which solves for both [Problems of Geodesy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesy#Geodetic_problems). It's a partial differential equation only solvable by iterative means, so it's not something Excel will do easily. If you cut the corner and solve on a sphere, you need to use the Law of Haversines.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not solving this problem within a GIS system? _Any_ GIS system would have the tools to quickly answer this, sounds like a simple select by location query to me?